# What will happen if android minimum versions changes ?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play

I need some clarifications on Android. For example I developed an application with min version of 2.3.3 and I uploaded to play store and next versions I mean coming versions was Implemented in min 4.0 because functions force me to do that. So How Play store will response ? Is it consider like new project or some thing else? What will happen for already installed 2.3.3 version user? Can any one explain this?

Comment: Simply, 2.3.3 users won't be able to update your app. Consider using the **support-library** and restore the minSdkVersion to (at least) 8

Comment: they will not get the update. I am the one with the device older than ICS

Comment: does app store will approve that type update APK's ?

Comment: Oh ok. Does that update will shown in 2.3.3 devices? I think No... Can I change the activities with respect to versions

Comment: Google will let you upload this new version to the Developer Console. But, to be professional to your 2.3 user base, you should post a comment in the app's description outlining this change so the users are aware of it. Users with Android 2.3 devices will not get the Update button if you make this change, but they can still see the What's New section in Google Play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the min SDK then users that dont have above 4.0 will not be able to get new versions of your app and they will be stuck on the version they have until they get a new device that meets you minimum sdk.

Its not a new project all you are doing is updating you current one